# Oracle LRS: Linear Referencing in Oracle

Tags: oracle, gis

Does anybody know how to do Linear Referencing in Oracle?

I have a table with my route geometries, like

```
id  routename   geometry
--  ---------   ----------
1   Mainstreet  SDO_GEOMETRY
2   5th Avenue  SDO_GEOMETRY
```

and I have a table with my events, like

```
id  routename   velocity  from   to
--  ---------   --------  ----   ----
1   Mainstreet  75mph     0.0    52.5
2   Mainstreet  45mph     52.5   102.0
3   5th Avenue  75mph     0.0    78.0
```

I want to get the events as standard SDO_GEOMETRIES, like:

```
id  routename   velocity  geometry
--  ---------   --------  --------
1   Mainstreet  75mph     SDO_GEOMETRY
2   Mainstreet  45mph     SDO_GEOMETRY
3   5th Avenue  75mph     SDO_GEOMETRY
```

In ArcGis or Geomedia it is very simple to achieve that... must be possible in Oracle I guess?

Comment: Should be possible on the fly, like in a select statement...

Comment: I'm guessing that the `SDO_GEOMETRY` values in the final result are different from the `SDO_GEOMETRY` values from the initial table.  I assume that the `from` and `to` values in the events table have some relationship to the `SDO_GEOMETRY` values in the route geometries table but I'm not sure what that relationship is.  Is your `route geometries` just a straight line, for example?

Comment: Yes, the result SDO_GEOMETRY should be a subpart of the original SDO_GEOMETRY. For example, the original SDO_GEOMETRY is a straight line, the event is from 0 to 52.5, then the resulting SDO_GEOMETRY should be the part from 0 to 52.5 of the original SDO_GEOMETRY with a length of 52.5.